# Can't start a new Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to start a new Rails project but I am getting a really strange error. When I do:

```
rails new my_project
```

I get a error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails ([">= 0"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

What should I do to start a new project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like rails isn't actually installed.

You can install it with `gem install rails`.

If it seems unlikely that it isn't installed, try running `gem list --local | grep "rails"`.

If it returns something, then make sure your rubygems aren't configured for a different ruby install by running `gem environment`.

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to imply rails isn't installed. Do you have RVM (Ruby Version Manager) installed? If you do, run `rvm install rails` in your terminal to install the latest version of rails

Answer (score 0):

`$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

or you can use

1 `$curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

2 `$rvm requirements`

3 `$sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config`

4 `$gem install rails`

Answer (score 0):

If you using a ruby version tool, that might be where the issue is. Check your current gemset, you may not be using the one you think you are.

I had the same problem, within RubyMine.

The issue was the rvm gemset that rails project create was defaulting to.
Was using  "RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p392",
need to be "RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p392 [global]".